# trying to read data file, store in array and print all the elements but it isnt working

Tags: c++, arrays

not sure what i'm doing wrong but this is my code

```
int main (){
int marks [100];
int i=0;
ifstream inputfile;
ofstream outputfile;
inputfile.open("data.txt");
 if(!inputfile.is_open())
 {
    cout<< "File did not open"<< endl;
    return 0;
 }
 cout<<"Marks in File:"<<endl;

 while (marks [i] != -1)
 {
    inputfile>>marks[i];
    cout << marks[i] <<endl;
    i++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

the output is messed up and returns stuff that was never in the data file to begin with

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, If you want to write some marks into a file you need to open it as `ofstream` so you can write on it. The other thing is that you never initial your `marks` array, it will contain some garbage values.

Comment: You're trying to check if a value is -1 before you're actually read it. Just step through this code line by line as if you're the computer. You should use a `while(true)` loop, and an if statement check if the inputted value is -1, then use `break` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal code for reading data from a file and write it to console. Description is added as comments

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream configrecord("D:\\Temp\\temp.txt");  //  opening the file named temp for reading.

    if(configrecord.good()) // check whether the file is opened properly.
    {  
        string line;
        while (getline(configrecord, line)) // reading a line from file to std::string
        {  
            cout << line; // printing the line, if you want it to store in an array, you can use the std::string::data() api to get the character pointer.
        }
        configrecord.close(); // closing the file after reading completed
    } 
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to read ints, and you're reading entire lines... I don't see how this has much to do with the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If we translate your code to English, we get:

1. Check if the current array element is -1, if it is, break the loop.
2. Read the value into the current array element.
3. Output the value.
4. Move to the next array element and repeat.

Notice a big problem: We're checking if the value is -1 before we actually read it. We need to reverse the order of steps 1 and 2 so that we get:

1. Read the value into the current array element.
2. Check if the current array element is -1, if it is, break the loop.
3. Output the value.
4. Move to the next array element and repeat.

We can do this by using `true` as our loop condition and then using an if statement to check if the inputted value is -1 later in the loop, using `break` to break the loop if it is.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std; is considered bad practice
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    int marks[100];
    //check if file is open stuff...
    for(int i = 0; true; i++)
    {
        inFile >> marks[i];
        if(marks[i] == -1) break;
        std::cout << marks[i] << '\n'; //endl flushes the buffer, unnecessary here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Of Note: it is good practice that if you use an if statement, you also include an else statement. Also, your while loop is confusing, because it stops if it encounters negative one, so I am assuming you know that integer -1 is not in the file.

```
int n = -1;
if(!inputfile.is_open())
{
   cout<< "File did not open"<< endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Marks in File:"<< endl;

    while(!inputfile.eof()){ // .eof is bad practice, but for this instance it works.
    File >> marks[n];
    n++; // Essentially the size of the array (Number of values), keeping track of how many values there are will assist you in the output process.
    }
}
```

When you are done reading the file, you should close it and then use the data in the array.

```
inputfile.close();
```

Lastly, in order to output an array of data, you must use a for loop or some type of iterator to access the values stored in the array.

```
for(int i=0; i < n ; i++) // Output array. Where array size is less than n.
{
    cout << marks[i] << " "; // " " inputs a space in between each word.
}
```

Comment: So if the file fails to open, you carry on with -1 items? That doesn't sound good.

Comment: One of the first things that you do is try to input into `marks[-1]`. You also have the `eof()` problem, which doesn't work in this instance if the file has a terminating newline, a very common thing. In fact, proper input/output files should end with a newline. If you know something is bad, don't teach it to someone new. [Why `eof()` in loop condition is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539).

Comment: No, it if fails to open, it outputs "File did not open". However, if that if statement is not tripped, then it goes to the else statement.